# Creating a job queue for a multi threaded server in C

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, queue, threadpool

I am working to design a multi threaded web server in C- goal is to have a boss/worker model with boss initializing the queue, main socket, and etc. then going into a loop where it accepts the new connections and enqueues the new socket descriptors on the queue for new workers.

!!!! EDIT: I have received some helpful feedback on this, and feel like I almost have it working implementing a linked list.. But there is something I am still missing here. When i run the server with a sample client, it does not worked as should (never starts sending files or showing output)

to be clear, i have the following as global variables

```
 ptreads.h
 pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
 pthread_cond_t c_boss = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
 pthread_cond_t c_worker = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

Queue structure:

```
//QUEUE STRUCTURE 
struct Node {
int data ;
struct Node * next;  // or link
};
struct Node* front = NULL;
struct Node* rear = NULL;

void Enqueue(int x){
           details
                }
void Dequeue(){
details
}
```

Main:

```
 ServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  bzero(&server, sizeof(server));
  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  server.sin_port = htons(HostPort);


bind(ServerSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));

listen(ServerSocket, max_pending_connections)


 pthread_t tid[numThreads];
int i;
for(i = 0; i <numThreads; i++){
pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, thread, NULL);
}

    while(1)

    while(front==NULL)
    {
    pthread_cond_wait (&c_boss, &mtx); 
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);

    enqueue(client_sock);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

    pthread_cond_signal(&c_worker);  

  }
```

and finally the worker thread:

```
void *thread(void * ServerSocket)

int   peer_socket =  *(int *) ServerSocket; // copy the socket
{
while(1){
pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);

while (front == NULL){
pthread_cond_wait(&c_worker, &mtx);}

peer_socket = Dequeue;

pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

pthread_cond_signal(&c_worker);

DOES WORK 
close(fd);       // close the file
      close(peer_socket); // close the client connection

      pthread_exit(NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would think a linked list (FIFO) queue would work best?

Yes, a doubly-linked list would work well for this application.  The boss thread can append items to the tail of the list, while the worker threads can pop items off of the head of the list.  (Make sure in both cases that the mutex is locked when these operations occur, of course)

The code you posted is on the right track; one thing you don't need to do (and shouldn't do) in the boss thread is block inside pthread_cond_wait().  Your boss thread will block inside accept(); there's no need (AFAIK) for it to block waiting for the queue to become empty.

I think the while loop in your worker-thread function can go away; there's no point in calling pthread_cond_wait() more than once in a row like that.  Instead, I would put a while(1) loop around the entire contents of that function, so that once the thread is done doing its WORK HERE it can go right back to waiting for the next job in the queue.  (Don't forget to close() the peer_socket when you're done using it)

Comment: You should ALWAYS call pthread_cond_wait() in a loop, the code is correct. Google "spurious wakeup"

Comment: I'd say that's a good reason to put an "if (peer_socket != NULL)" around the "WORK HERE" section; but there's still no need for a loop around the pthread_cond_wait() call since a spurious wakeup would be handled correctly by the outer while(1) loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback - I added an edit as I am still having some serious problems with the queue, any help is definitely appreciated

Comment: Enqueue() seems to be trying to add the node to the second position in the list, rather than to the end of the list.  Enqueue() never sets newNode->tail; Dequeue() never unsets head->prev.